# get_users when from meta key that has serialized values

Tags: php, user-meta, array

I am trying to do a `get_users()` when the meta key has two values. For instance, in the db it looks like this :

```
a:2:{i:0;s:10:"31.08.2017";i:1;s:9:"username";}
```

When I do my query :

```
$claimed_users = get_users('meta_key=username');
```

and try to output it : `print_r($claimed_users);`

it just returns `Array()`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The meta_*key* has two values? That's... strange. Do you mean the meta_value is has two values?

Comment: try `var_dump($claimed_users);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the meta_value has a serialized array, not the meta_key (For it would make no sense to have the meta_key to be a serialized array)

You really should save the values in seperate fields to be able to query it by wordpress internal functions like get_users.

If you definitely have to preserve this data-structure, you have to go by directly accessing the Database by wpdb like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$claimed_user_ids = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = %s AND meta_value LIKE %s",'<META_KEY>','%username%'));
```

(replace  with the meta_key which holds the serialized array).

Happy Coding, Kuchenundkakao